# element stuck on upper right corner even with top:1000px

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can get my div items off the upper right corner. I've tired everything I can think of but for some reason I cannot get the blog div to move off the top right corner

The CSS

```
#nav {
position: fixed; 
min-width:690px;
white-space:nowrap;
text-align:left;
margin:0;
padding:40px 0 34px 333px;
z-index:999;
}

#nav a {    
font-family: Micra, serif;
color: #FFF;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:400;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:100%;
margin:0 25px 0 0;
}

#nav1 {
position: fixed; 
top:70px; 
min-width:690px;
white-space:nowrap;
text-align:left;
margin:0;
padding:0px 0 64px 472px;
z-index: 9999;
}

#nav1 a {
font-family: Micra, serif;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:400;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:80%;
margin:0 55px 0 0;
}

#blog  {
float:right;
list-style:none;
top:1000px;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="nav">
  <a href="#Bot">DUCATI TRACKER</a>
  <a href="#Bot">EARLE MOTORS</a>       
  <a href="#Bot">PUBLICATIONS</a>
  </div>

<div id="nav1">
  <a href="#Bot">SERVICES</a>   
  <a href="#Bot">SPECS</a>
  <a href="#Bot">PRESS</a>      
</div>
 <div id="blog">
    <a href="#">dsds</a>
    <a href="#">aaaa</a>
    <a href="#">dddd</a>  
</div>
```

The blog div is the one stuck in the upper right corner

Comment: Your CSS seems to be generally off... it's hard to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a logo on the left side, 3 links just to the left of the logo going horizontal then to the far right a blog link. Under the 3 links is another set of 3 links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the problem is that you haven't set the blog div to `position:fixed/relative;` or the like - I don't think your `top:1000px` is being applied. Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Knr8/

Answer (score 0):

If you use float:right, it becomes free from the document flow and tries to take a top free position in the right corner. To define the position from top, you need to first declare the position.

position:relative;

If you define position:fixed; it will get stuck at the same position and will not move with page scroll.